# Inconsistent Handler behavior

Tags: android, service, handler

I am using a handler inside my service to display notifications at a certain time using the `Handler.postDelayed` method. My application runs fine on the emulator just as expected satisfying all cases. But when I installed the same on my HTC Wildfire, it simply doesn't happen as anticipated. Notifications are displayed at a random manner after the scheduled time and some notifications even fail. I'm monitoring my service from the Applications > Running Services and still my service is active. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this from the Handler documentation

> If the looper is quit before the
>   delivery time of the message occurs
>   then the message will be dropped.

So, instead of using a **Handler** with a **Runnable**, I used a **Timer** with a **TimerTask**.